# unable to write junit test for controller class where spring bean naming strategy is used

Tags: nullpointerexception, junit5

I am having trouble to create a Junit-Mockito test for a controller class where service class is derived runtime based on input parameter passed to API (Spring bean naming strategy)

I have tried BeforeEach to initialize the mapper but no luck, any suggestions will be helpful

## Controller Code

@RestController
public class TestController {

```
@Autowired
Map<String,TestInterface> mapper;

@GetMapping("/test")
public String handleNew(@RequestHeader String serviceType) {
    TestInterface service = mapper.get(serviceType);
    String result = service.handleNewPowerMock();
    return result;
}
```

}

## Test

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ControllerTest {

```
@InjectMocks
TestController controller;

@Mock
Map<String,TestInterface> mapper;

@Mock
Map<String, Integer> map;
    
@Test
public void test_mock() throws Exception {
    try(MockedConstruction<TestServiceA> service = Mockito.mockConstruction(TestServiceA.class)){
        TestController controller = new TestController();
        when(mapper.get("A"))
        .thenReturn(new TestServiceA());
        controller.handleNew("A");
    }
}
```

## Exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.util.Map.get(Object)" because "this.mapper" is null
at com.test.TestController.handleNew(TestController.java:18)
at com.test.ControllerTest2.test_mock(ControllerTest2.java:47)

Tried using different options to make this test success, but all attempts ended with same exception